# Идентификатор не найден С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

Я  объявил переменную все ок при запуске выдает мне что идентификатор не найден. Это как?
Вот код функции в CircleDoubleList.h :

```
template<typename T>
inline void CircleDoubleList<T>::add(T value)
{
    
    if (this->head == nullptr) {
        Collection<T>::Node* temp = new typename Collection<T>::Node(value);
        this->head = temp;
        this->tail = temp;
        this->head->prev = this->tail;
        this->tail->next = this->head;
    }
    else
    {
        Collection<T>::Node* temp = new typename Collection<T>::Node(value,nullptr,nullptr);
        this->head->next = temp;
        this->tail->prev = temp;
        this->tail = temp;

    }
}
```

А это код Node в Collection.h:

```
class Node      // Класс для элемента связной структуры
    {
    public:
        Node();     // Конструктор по умолчанию
        Node(T value, Node* prev = nullptr, Node* next = nullptr); // Конструктор с параметрами
        Node(const Node& node); // Конструктор копирования
        ~Node();                // Деструктор

        T value;                // Значение данных
        Node* next;             // Указатель на следующий элемент
        Node* prev;             // Указатель на предыдущий элемент
    };
```

Реализация методов Node:

```
template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Node::Node()
{
    this->value = nullptr;
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Node::Node(T value, Node* prev, Node* next)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->prev = prev;
    this->next = next;
}

template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Node::Node(const Node& node)
{
    this->value = node.value;
    this->prev = node.prev;
    this->next = node.next;
}

template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Node::~Node()
{
    delete this->prev;
    delete this->next;
}
```

Comment: Так же вопрос это может быть из-за сбоя в Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: А на какую строку ругается компилятор? Подозреваю, что он просто не может увидеть переменную, объявленную внутри фигурных скобок, но адресуемую вне их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого, оказалось, что нужно использовать ***uniform-инициализацию***

```
typename Collection<T>::Node* insertNode = { new typename Collection<T>::Node(value) };
```

И вот таким образом инициализировать `Node*`.
[Спасибо вот этому человеку!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/442516/wusiki-jeronii)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
inline void CircleDoubleList<T>::add(T value)
```

А зачем вы функцию/метод объявили как `inline`? Вся суть `inline` функций что компилятор может её не включать в vtable. И тогда ссылки вызова фактически не будет. Код из функции будет просто поставляться. Работает по аналогии с миксинами из других языков. В результате `this` - это неопределенное поведение в таких функциях. К сожалению, по коду из сообщения сложно понять контекст использования. Но я предполагаю что из-за этого и возникает ошибка. Пожалуйста поясните причину использования `inline` и отредактируйте код с примером использования. Заранее извиняюсь что комментария используется как ответ. Недостаточно рейтинга, но я здесь чтобы помочь

```cpp
Collection<T>::Node* temp = new typename Collection<T>::Node(value);
        this->head = temp;
```

Это первое что бросилось в глаза. Другой момент что тоже увидел - что из себя представляет `this->head`?
Вы пытаетесь переменной назначить тип? Потому что `temp` в вашем коде это тип, а не значение, и не идиентфикатор

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ну IDE мне просто сама предлагала так определить функцию. Но даже после того как я убрал inline ошибки никуда не делись и остались теми же)

Comment: ну почему? temp - это указатель типа Node . а new typename Collection<T>::Node(value) - это обращение к конструктору.  Collection<T>::Node* head = nullptr;  - это head

Comment: Я не самый опытный c++ программист и не могу точно объяснить почему, но я считаю это ошибкой. Как по мне более корректно `Collection<T>::Node* temp = new Collection<T>::Node(value);` Таким образом temp - это именно lvalue. Так у вас также возникает ошибка?

Comment: я так изначально и хотел написать, но компилятор не пускает и не видит тогда этот конструктор и просит указать typename (ОШИБКА C7510 - "Node": при использовании зависимого имени тип необходимо указать префикс "имя типа")

Comment: А какую ошибку пишет компилятор?

Comment: А всё вижу. Вам нужно указать тип значения при вызове конструктора. `Collection<T>::Node* temp = new Collection<T>::Node<T>(value)`

Comment: Не так тоже нельзя. В классе Node  в самом нет шаблонов (Е0519 - класс "Collection<T>::Node [с T=int]" не может содержать список аргументов шаблона )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140446/discussion-between-wusiki-jeronii-and--).

Answer (score -1):

Ну тебе просто надо объявление переменной  за скобки вынести или в майн

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не сильно помогло)